# TypeScript error on RegEx input parameter

Tags: typescript

I just started converting JavaScript to TypeScript, and this line:

```
 var re = new RegExp(/<script>(<h2.*?)<\/script>/g);
```

is showing error :

> Augument of type 'RegEx' is not assignable to parameters of type
>   'string'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you have is duplicative -- it creates a RegExp using the built-in syntax, then creates another RegExp via the constructor function. You can write either of these instead (they are equivalent):

```
var re = /<script>(<h2.*?)<\/script>/g;
```

or

```
var re = new RegExp('<script>(<h2.*?)<\/script>', 'g');
```

Comment: Thanks very much for quick response. TypeScript rocks.